# GVim runs very slowly when editing files on a windows share

Tags: performance, networking, vim

On my computer at work, any time I open a file located on a network share, GVim becomes completely unusable. Scrolling through the document can take 15 seconds to go one "page". Even using the movement keys to go from one word to another can take 2 to 3 seconds. This seems to be a new behavior, but for the life of me I can't remember changing anything that would cause it. I'm under the impression that Vim doesn't actually access a file except on open and on save. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, but your swap file may be on the network, which may cause some slowdown. Also note that if you have extremely long lines and syntax highlighting enabled, sometimes vim will slow to a crawl.

Comment: Since you suggest that something's changed, have you tried opening without your vimrc or any plugins? There are plenty of things you could've added there that could cause more frequent reads and writes. (The swap file's a good bet too though)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Swap file has nothing to do with it. I have my swap file local and still have the problem. I use Process Monitor from SysInternals.com and it revealed bad behavior when attempting to open "\server\TestTool\foo\ReadMe.TXT"

It first attempts a CreateFile (aka, Directory open) on "\serve\". Notice the last character is missing. This will cause 4 seconds to time out with "OBJECT PATH INVALID".

Then it tries CreateFile on "\server\TestToo\". Server name is correct by the last letter of "TestTool" is clipped. Again, a 3 second time out with "BAD NETWORK NAME".

Finally it gets it right and calls CreateFile on "\server\TestTool\" which works right away.
Then CreateFile on "\server\TestTool\foo" which works right away.
Then CreateFile on "\server\TestTool\foo\ReadMe.TXT" which works right away.

WHY is it trying bad names for the server and the root directory??? What madness is this?

Comment: I downloaded the source code and found the problem. They are using FindFirstFile() which is not supposed to be used on root directories or network shares. Bug in vim. I'm going to try fixing it.

Comment: ten years later and this bug is still at large ... I've tried all of the other fixes in this thread, it has to be this ...

Answer (score 11):

There are a few factors which may affect this.

First, make sure you have Vim setup to prefer storing the swapfile locally.  If your `$HOME` is on a local drive, I tend to put this in my vimrc (which will either be at `$HOME\_vimrc` or `$VIM\_vimrc`).  Make sure you create that directory, otherwise Vim will continue to use one of the other directories in the list.

```
set directory^=$HOME/tmp
```

This prepends the `$HOME/tmp` directory to the start of the list that Vim checks for where to place swapfiles.

Second, do the same for the backup file that Vim creates.  Same situation as above but the option you'll be changing is `backupdir` instead of `directory`.

Third, make sure you disable the matchparen plugin.  This plugin is new to Vim 7, so you may be used to using an older version of Vim.  This causes frequent scanning of the file for matching parens, braces, etc. which can drastically slow Vim down when the file is on a network share.  Again, this should go in your vimrc.

```
let g:loaded_matchparen = 1
```

If you only want to disable the plugin temporarily, you can use the command `:NoMatchParen` and then `:DoMatchParen` to re-enable it later in that Vim session.

Finally, if none of those help you can always copy the file locally and edit it.

Comment: It was the matchparen plugin. I turned it off and everything went back to normal. The moment I turned it back on, Vim hung again. Thanks!

Comment: I had this same problem.  `:NoMatchParen` gets me right back to the snappy vim I love. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this issue after setting HOME path by force in advanced system settings.
(Your current HOME path would be a network directory.)

> Control Panel > All Control Panel Items > System > Advanced system settings > Environment variables
>
> Press "New..."
>
> Variable name: **HOME**
>
> Variable value: `c:\Home\   **<-- Type your home directory**`

Comment: This answer helped me a lot for gvim version 8.0.

Answer (score 2):

A follow up on jamessan's answer: to disable the plugin automatically when you edit files on a  share, put this line in you _vimrc

```
autocmd BufReadPre //* :NoMatchParen
```

Answer (score 1):

You could consider installing [LargeFile](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1506) plugin. It disables a couple of features impacting the performance.

Answer (score 1):

Having a similar issue as *David Anderson*, but no solution yet.

When loading `\\ServerName\A$\B\C\File.txt` Vim will do:

- Open \ServerName\A$\B\C\File.txt

Then it does many loops like:

- **CreateFile \ServerName\A$** <-- Each taking roughly 1 sec
- QueryDirectory \ServerName\A$\B
- QueryDirectory \ServerName\A$
- QueryDirectory \ServerName\A$\B\C
- QueryDirectory \ServerName\A$\B

To compare with Notepad++ which loads files almost instantaneously there are more lines and Notepad++ never queries `\\ServerName\A$`.

Also the duration (*Duration* column) written in Process Monitor is low, but the time taken by Vim seem quiet high (*Time of Day* column) for the CreateFile `\\ServerName\A$`.

I've no plugins installed as far as I know and followed other tips to speed up network shares loading.

Note: The dollar is in the path. More weird is that **Vim will load very fast** on more recent *Windows Server* (2008 instead of 2003) with the  same folder structure.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (slow gvim editing over network drive) and have fixed it. It was for me -- no kidding -- the `titlestring`.

Background: I use a vertically arranged taskbar with Windows 10. This has the advantage that my open windows behave like a growing stack from top to bottom. For example, see here some currently open windows with `how-to-run.txt` as a network file:

[image: example of my Windows taskbar]

With that it makes sense, that the **filename** is going **first** in the window title of gvim and the path goes after that. So I used exactly the `titlestring` in my `vimrc`, which is still officially recommended in the help file `vim81/doc/options.txt`, line 8202:

```
set titlestring=%t%(\ %M%)%(\ (%{expand(\"%:~:.:h\")})%)%(\ %a%)
```

For local files that's ok, but for network files this is way too slow.

Now my fix:

```
set titlestring=
```

Same effect (filename first), but now gvim runs very fast for remote files as well!

BTW, I also tried all the above mentioned recommendations (`directory`, `backupdir`, `matchparen`, disabled all the plugins, tried the `LargeFile` plugin although I observed the slow gvim also for small files, etc.). I also changed my `statusline` to something really simple.

It **all** had **no** effect for me. But the funny `titlestring`...